# Calling parent module methods from a nested class

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a method from a parent module in a class.

I want to call module functions from parent module in my nested classes, but can't seem to find a way how to do this.

example:

```
module Awesome
  class Checker
    def awesome?
      awesome_detection
    end
  end

  module_function
  def awesome_detection
    true
  end

end
```

If I call `Awesome::Checker.new.awesome?`, it's unaware of `awesome_detection`

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Just remembered — I realized I could do `include Awesome` in checker, but want to know a different way if I have multiple classes within `Awesome`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

module Awesome

  class Checker
    def awesome?
      Awesome.awesome_detection
    end
  end

  def self.awesome_detection
    puts "yes"
  end

end

Awesome::Checker.new.awesome?
# => yes
```

Comment: The `module_function` in the original question was better. Fixing the `def awesome?` to call `Awesome.awesome_detection` would have been enough.

Comment: it seems redundant, calling `Awesome.awsome...`   inside `module Awesome`isn't it?